# Are Fetched Properties KVO compliant?

Tags: core-data, fetch, key-value-observing

Strange behavior into my Core Data application. I have an entity with a fetched property, whose result is stored into the content array of a controller.

The first time I run the application, the result is NIL for the first entity of the controller's array (not for the others). If I re-launch the app, everything is ok.

Is the controller really informed that a new object has been added to its array? If yes, why so late? Did you ever encountered such an anomaly?

Regards,